# How can I show that the operator $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x_n}{2^{n+1}}$ does not take it's norm in $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, operator-theory

> Let us consider $c_0=\{(x_n)_n\subset \Bbb{R}: \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=0\}$ with $||x||_\infty=\sup_n |x_n|$. Then define $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x_n}{2^{n+1}}$.

I have proven that $||F||=1$. But now I want to show if this norm is realized in $c_0$ i.e. if there exists $x\in c_0$ such that $||x||=1$ and $|F(x)|=||F||$.

Therefore I assume that there exists $x\in c_0$ with $||x||=1$ and $|F(x)|=||F||=1$. Since $x_n\rightarrow 0$ we know that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, $|x_n|<\epsilon$. now consider $$\begin{align} \left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x_n}{2^{n+1}}\right|&\leq \left|\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{x_n}{2^{n+1}}\right|+\left|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{2^{n+1}}\right|\\&\leq \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{|x_n|}{2^{n+1}}+\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{|x_n|}{2^{n+1}}\\&<\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{|x_n|}{2^{n+1}}+\epsilon \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\\&\leq\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}+\epsilon \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\\&<\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=1\end{align}$$
Where in the last inequality I used that $\epsilon$ is small enough. But this would then be a contradiction to the assumption. Hence I would say that the norm is not realized in $c_0$.

Is this true ?

Comment: Your proof is fine. It can be generalized to any functional of the form $F(x)=\sum a_nx_n$ where $\sum |a_n|<\infty$ and $a_n\neq 0$ for infinitely many $n.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc oh thanks a lot I didn't expect that it is fine. Would your generalization also holds if $a_n\rightarrow 0$ without the boundedness of the serie?

Comment: No, the condition $\sum |a_n|<\infty$ is necessary as it can be shown that $\|F\|=\sum |a_n|.$ In my previous comment I meant that your proof goes through in the case I have indicated.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc ah I see thanks!